# How to change a TabBar location in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In my app I want to be able to place a UIView under my TabBar (to use ad banner). I successfully implemented the UIView, but I can't change the TabBar location (the TabBar to be above the UIView). I try solutions for iOS 13 and early but they don't work on iOS 14. My UIView still is in the foreground over the TabBar.
[image: my]

An example of how I want it to be:
[image: example]

My code now:

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
...
lazy var bannerAd: UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
   view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   view.backgroundColor = .green
   return view
}()
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   view.addSubview(bannerAd)
   bannerAd.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
   bannerAd.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
   bannerAd.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
}
...
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
   self.tabBar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
   var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame
   tabFrame.size.height = tabBarHeight
   tabFrame.origin.y = tabFrame.origin.y - 44
   self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try ( key is in using `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewWillLayoutSubviews` )

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
 
    lazy var bannerAd: UIView = {
       let view = UIView()
       view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       view.backgroundColor = .green
       return view
    }()
     
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       view.addSubview(bannerAd)
       bannerAd.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
       bannerAd.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
       bannerAd.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
       bannerAd.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }
     
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       self.tabBar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
       var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame
       tabFrame.size.height = 44
       tabFrame.origin.y = tabFrame.origin.y - 44
       self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
       }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Omg! It works! You saved my day)) Thank you so much. Can you tell me why it doesn't work in the viewWillLayoutSubviews()?

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is prior to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in call stack you should use the latter where correct frames are calculated and ready for a change

Comment: Perhaps you tell me how can I return the location of the tabBar while the application is running? For example, I want to hide the banner and for the tabBar to return to its place.